# How to use a batch_size < num_sample with a dataset under keras.model.fit?

Tags: python, keras

My dataset if formated with a batch of 1000 as : 56x((1000,4,1),(1000,1)) :

- 56 elements
- Each element with shape (1000,4,1) for x_training and (1000,1) for y_label

When I use model.fit(dataset), **1000 samples are used to calculate the loss** and the number of iterations is 56 per ecpoch. So **there is 1000 step per epoch**.

How can I force keras to use, say 56 samples for calculating the loss : I would like to do something like model.fit(batch_size=56, dataset) but the batch_size is not take into account when using dataset.

Without dataset, if I use two tensors and want to use a batch_size of 1000 by doing :

- x_train : (56000,4,1)
- y_train : (56000)

And I do : model.fit(**batch_size=1000**, x=x_train, y=y_train)

Then it works : **only 56 samples are used for calculating the loss**, and there still have 56 iterations per epoch. So it seems **there is 1000 sample used per epoch**.

To summarize : In each case there is 56 step per epoch, with 1000 sample used per epoch. But with dataset, 1000 sampled are used to calculate the loss, and without it only 56 are used.

Is I use a batch of 56 for the dataset, it will make 1000 elements and so the total time to fit the model will be the same... (it will do 1000 step per epoch)

I would like to reduce the total calculation as it works when I don't use dataset...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: batch_size doesn't work with generators. please include how you created the dataset

Comment: ok thanks you ! I used a batch_size of 1000 with my dataset, but if i use a batch_size of 56 it will create 1000 elements and time will be the same to calculate all the things...

Comment: batch_size is disabled if model.fit() if you're using a generator